# Replace value i with range 1:i in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, count

If I have the following vector:

```
x = [3;2;4];
```

is there a way that I can replace each value with its range, i.e.

```
[1;2;3;1;2;1;2;3;4]
```

I tried the following:

```
y=zeros(9,1);
y(1:x(1)) = 1:x(1);
```

this gives me

```
[1;2;3;0;0;0;0;0;0];
```

But I don't know how to proceed with the 2nd element of vector x and turn it into a loop. Also, it would be nice to have the counts go backwards, i.e.

```
[3;2;1;2;1;4;3;2;1]
```

but I couldn't come up with a function for this. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `arrayfun` and `cell2mat`:

```
>> x = [3;2;4];
>> y = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(k) (1:k).', x, 'UniformOutput', false))

y =

     1
     2
     3
     1
     2
     1
     2
     3
     4
```

For the backwards case, you can let the indices run backwards:

```
>> y = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(k) (k:-1:1).', x, 'UniformOutput', false))

y =

     3
     2
     1
     2
     1
     4
     3
     2
     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized way. For the **forward** case:

```
s = cumsum(x);
y = ones(s(end),1);
y(s(1:end-1)+1)=1-x(1:end-1);
y = cumsum(y);
```

For the **backward** case: include `x = x(end:-1:1)` at the beginning and `y = y(end:-1:1)` at the end:

```
x = x(end:-1:1);
s = cumsum(x);
y = ones(s(end),1);
y(s(1:end-1)+1)=1-x(1:end-1);
y = cumsum(y);
y = y(end:-1:1);
```

The two above snippets assume that `x` doesn't contain any zeros. If it does, use `x = nonzeros(x);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use horzcat():

```
x = [3;2;4];

% forwards
x2 = [];
for i=1:length(x)
    x2 = horzcat(x2,1:1:x(i));
end
x2

% backwards
x2 = [];
for i=1:length(x)
    x2 = horzcat(x2,x(i):-1:1);
end
x2
```